# Gets null in parameter on post request in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jboss7.x

I have a form and that form is submitted to a Spring action with post method.
But I got null on parameters when submitted with post method. If I change the method to GET, I received the parameter correctly.

My JSP :

```
<form name="loginForm" action="192.168.100.139:8880/authenticateLescUsers.do" method="POST" >
    <div class="login-cont">
        <input id="login" name="login" type="text" class="username cleardefault" value="<%=cn%>" size="23" />
        <input name="passwd" id="passwd" type="password" class="password cleardefault" value="" size="23" />
        <input type="hidden" name="isAutoLogin" id="isAutoLogin" value="false" />
        <button class="login">Login</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

My Spring Action:

```
   @Controller
    public class LoginController {
    
    
        @RequestMapping(value = "/authenticateLescUsers", method = {
            RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET })
        public ModelAndView authenticateLescUser(
            @RequestParam("login") String loginId,
            @RequestParam("passwd") String passwd,
            @RequestParam(required=false) String domain,
            @RequestParam("isAutoLogin") String autoLogin, ModelMap model,
            HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpSession session) {
        
            System.out.println(autoLogin);
            return null;
        }
        
    }
```

I receive null on all of my parameters and following error appears on browser:
**"The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect."**

Don't really know what I am missing out here.
Thanks for help!

Comment: what happens if you change: <button class="login">Login</button>
 to <input type="submit" text="Login"/> ???

Comment: first of all, you need to supply a parameter name to bind to on the domain.

Comment: I've also tried with <input type="submit" text="Login"/> , but no change in error

Comment: I have already supplied each parameter with a name.

Comment: I doesn't need to return according to my business, so I returned null for that case. But I don't think so it is some-what related the error I am facing.

Comment: In action attribute, why do you have authenticateLescUsers.do instead of just authenticateLescUsers

Comment: authenticateLescUsers.do is because I have configured it in web.xml that all requests with "*.do" url pattern should be served by "org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet"

Comment: By submitting the form using GET method, It runs successfully. Only gives the mentioned error when the form is submitted by using POST method.

Comment: There is no need to add your `host` detalis in your `action` attribute, just say `action="/authenticateLescUsers.do"`